# Drools performance for decision tables

Tags: java, drools

I have a potential performance/memory bottleneck when I try to calculate insurance premium using Drools engine.

I use Drools in my project to separate business logic from java code and I decided to use it for premium calculation too.

- Am I using Drools the wrong way?
- How to meet the requirements in more performant way?

Details below:

---

### Calculations

I have to calculate insurance premium for given contract.

**Contract** is configured with

- productCode (code from dictionary)
- contractCode (code from dictionary)
- client’s personal data (e.g. age, address)
- insurance sum (SI)
- etc.

At the moment, **premium** is calculated using this **formula**:

```
premium := SI * px * (1 + py) / pz
```

where:

- **px** is **factor** parameterized in Excel file and **depends** on 2 properties (client’s age and sex)
- **py** is **factor** parameterized in excel file and **depends** on 4 contract’s properties
- **pz** - similarly

---

### Requirements

- **R1** – java code doesn’t know the **formula**,
- **R2** - java code knows nothing about **formula dependencies**, in other words that premium depends on:  px, py, pz,
- **R3** - java code knows nothing about **parameters’ dependencies**, I mean that px depends on client’s age and sex, and so on.

With R1, R2 and R3 implemented I have java code in separation from business logic, and any business analyst (BA) may modify formula and add new dependencies without redeploys.

---

### My solution, so far

I have **contract domain model**, which consists of classes Contract, Product, Client, Policy and so on. Contract class is defined as:

```
public class Contract {

    String code;           // contractCode
    double sumInsured;     // SI
    String clientSex;      // M, F
    int professionCode;    // code from dictionary
    int policyYear;        // 1..5
    int clientAge;         // 
    ...                    // etc.
```

In addition I introduced **Var** class that is container for **any** parameterized variable:

```
public class Var {

    public final String name;
    public final ContractPremiumRequest request;

    private double value;       // calculated value
    private boolean ready;      // true if value is calculated

    public Var(String name, ContractPremiumRequest request) {
        this.name = name;
        this.request = request;
    }

    ... 
    public void setReady(boolean ready) {
        this.ready = ready;
        request.check();
    }

    ...
    // getters, setters
}
```

and finally - **request** class:

```
public class ContractPremiumRequest {

    public static enum State {
        INIT,
        IN_PROGRESS,
        READY
    }

    public final Contract contract;

    private State state = State.INIT;

    // all dependencies (parameterized factors, e.g. px, py, ...)
    private Map<String, Var> varMap = new TreeMap<>();

    // calculated response - premium value 
    private BigDecimal value;

    public ContractPremiumRequest(Contract contract) {
        this.contract = contract;
    }

    // true if *all* vars are ready
    private boolean _isReady() {
        for (Var var : varMap.values()) {
            if (!var.isReady()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // check if should modify state
    public void check() {
        if (_isReady()) {
            setState(State.READY);
        }
    }

    // read number from var with given [name]
    public double getVar(String name) {
        return varMap.get(name).getValue();
    }

    // adding uncalculated factor to this request – makes request IN_PROGRESS
    public Var addVar(String name) {
        Var var = new Var(name, this);
        varMap.put(name, var);

        setState(State.IN_PROGRESS);
        return var;
    }

    ...
    // getters, setters
}
```

***Now I can use these classes with such flow:***

1. `request = new ContractPremiumRequest(contract)`

   - creates request with `state == INIT`
2. `px = request.addVar( "px" )`

   - creates `Var("px")` with `ready == false`
   - moves request to `state == IN_PROGRESS`
3. `py = request.addVar( "py" )`
4. `px.setValue( factor )`, `px.setReady( true )`

   - set calculated value on `px`
   - makes it `ready == true`
5. `request.check()` makes `state == READY` if **ALL** vars are ready
6. now we can use formula, as request has all dependencies calculated

I have created **2 DRL rules** and prepared **3 decision tables** (px.xls, py.xls, ...) with factors provided by BA.

**Rule1 - contract_premium_prepare.drl:**

```
rule "contract premium request - prepare dependencies"
when
  $req : ContractPremiumRequest (state == ContractPremiumRequest.State.INIT)
then
  insert( $req.addVar("px") ); 
  insert( $req.addVar("py") ); 
  insert( $req.addVar("pz") ); 
  $req.setState(ContractPremiumRequest.State.IN_PROGRESS);
end
```

**Rule2 - contract_premium_calculate.drl:**

```
rule "contract premium request - calculate premium"
when 
  $req : ContractPremiumRequest (state == ContractPremiumRequest.State.READY)
then 
  double px = $req.getVar("px"); 
  double py = $req.getVar("py");
  double pz = $req.getVar("pz");
  double si = $req.contract.getSumInsured();  

  // use formula to calculate premium 
  double premium = si * px * (1 + py) / pz; 

  // round to 2 digits 
  $req.setValue(premium);
end
```

**Decision table px.xls:**

[image: Fragment from px.xls decision table]

**Decision table py.xls:**

[image: Fragment from px.xls decision table]

**KieContainer is constructed once on startup:**

```
dtconf = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
dtconf.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kc = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
```

**Now to calculate premium for given contract we write:**

```
ContractPremiumRequest request = new ContractPremiumRequest(contract);  // state == INIT
kc.newStatelessKieSession("session-rules").execute(request);
BigDecimal premium = request.getValue();
```

**This is what happens:**

- **Rule1** fires for `ContractPremiumRequest[INIT]`
- this rule creates and adds px, py and pz dependencies (`Var` objects)
- proper excel row **fires** for each px, py, pz object and **makes it ready**
- **Rule2** fires for `ContractPremiumRequest[READY]` and use formula

---

### Volumes

- PX decision table has **~100** rows,
- PY decision table has **~8000** rows,
- PZ decision table has **~50** rows.

---

### My results

- First calculation, which loads and initializes decision tables takes **~45 seconds** – this might become problematic.
- Each calculation (after some warmup) takes **~0.8 ms** – which is acceptable for our team.
- Heap consumption is **~150 MB** – which is problematic as we expect much more big tables will be used.

---

### Question

- Am I using Drools the wrong way?
- How to meet the requirements in more performant way?
- How to optimize memory usage?

**========== EDIT (after 2 years) ==========**

This is a short summary after 2 years.

Our system has grown very much, as we expected. We have ended with more then 500 tables (or matrices) with insurance pricing, actuarial factors, coverage configs etc.
Some tables are more than 1 million rows in size. We used drools but we couldn't handle performance problems.

Finally we have used **Hyperon** engine (http://hyperon.io)

This system is a beast - it allows us to run hundreds rule matches in approx 10 ms total time.

We were even able to trigger full policy recalculation on every KeyType event on UI fields.

As we have learnt, Hyperon uses fast in-memory indexes for each rule table and these indexes are somehow compacted so they offer almost no memory footprint.

We have one more benefit now - all pricing, factors, config tables can be modified on-line (both values and structure) and this is fully transparent to java code. 
Application just continues to work with new logic, no development or restart is needed.

However we have needed some time and effort to get to know Hyperon well enough :)

I have found some comparison made by our team a year ago - it shows engine initialization (drools/hyperon) and 100k simple calculations from jvisualVM perspective:

[image: Policy calculation with drools]
[image: Policy calculation with hyperon]

Comment: You deserve something for all the work you put into creating this question.  There isn't a right or wrong way; it's whether it meets your requirements or not.

Comment: 150MB seems like a small amount of memory to me. You should be running on a 64 bit OS with a lot of memory. No less than 8 GB. Measure and profile under a realistic load to know what you have.

Comment: Those table sizes are small. Either one will work. Choose based on other considerations: development expertise, ease of updating, etc.

Comment: @duffymo Yes, I will run my app in 64 bit with more than 8GB, but I will have more than 100 excel files with some bigger than 50k rows. And I expect memory problems if I see 150MB on heap for single 8k rows decision table.

Comment: See my answer. You should not be using Excel. Get a relational database.

Comment: @duffymo You mean put all factors to dedicated DB tables and fetch them without Drools?

Comment: @duffymo I am inexperienced in Drools so it is possible that I'm not using some feature I should. Do you think it is correct to put PremiumRequest to session, then fire rule that puts another dependent objects (px,py,pz), and finally read result from filled PremiumRequest? Or maybe there is some in-memory compression feature?

Comment: I'll reply in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have created a huge amount of code (all the rules resulting from the tables) for what is a relatively small amount of data. I have seen similar cases, and they all benefited from inserting the tables as data. PxRow, PyRow and PzRow should be defined like this:

```
class PxRow { 
    private String gender;
    private int age;
    private double px;
    // Constructor (3 params) and getters
}
```

Data can still be in (simpler) spreadsheets or anything else you fancy for data entry by the BA boffins. You insert all rows as facts PxRow, PyRow, PzRow. Then you need one or two rules:

```
rule calculate
when 
    $c: Contract( $cs: clientSex, $ca: clientAge,
                  $pc: professionCode, $py: policyYear,...
                  ...
                  $si: sumInsured )

    PxRow( gender == $cs, age == $ca, $px: px )
    PyRow( profCode == $pc, polYear == $py,... $py: py )
    PzRow( ... $pz: pz )
then
    double premium = $si * $px * (1 + $py) / $pz; 
    // round to 2 digits 
    modify( $c ){ setPremium( premium ) }
end
```

Forget the flow and all the other decorations. But you may need another rule just in case your Contract doesn't match Px or Py or Pz:

```
rule "no match"
salience -100
when
    $c: Contract( premium == null ) # or 0.00
then
    // diagnostic
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - this is completely different approach which I did not consider. I can see advantages in fact that all Excel rows are not converted to rules but rather **used as facts** and put in bulk into session. This I think would **save much memory**. 
However this approach does not meet the requirements (_see Requirements section in my question_). Unfortunately, requirement **R2 is not met**, as now java code has to put all `PxRow`, ..., `PzRow` objects into session so java code has to know that formula depends on px, ..., pz.

Comment: Similarly, **R3 is not met**, as now we have to implement parameterized factors as java classes (`PxRow`, etc.) and put their dependencies as class fields (`PxRow.clientAge`, ..., `PyRow.policyYear`).
The calculation example I have shown in question **was simplified** to focus on mechanics and dependency management. In our project we will have **hundreds formulas** with some logic (good for DRL) and **hundreds matrixes** with factors depended on different properties. BAs want to modify matrixes and their columns (dependencies) and data quite often (once a week) – that why **R2** and **R3**.

Comment: My solution, which is **proof of concept only**, works with **R2** and **R3**, but I am upset with heap usage (for small matrix) and matrix initialization time. Single calculation time is fast enough (0.8ms).
Maybe I should not use Drools for such scenario? Maybe the Drools’ strength lies elsewhere, in inference or reasoning usages? I am asking as inexperienced Drools' user :)

Comment: You are wrong on both counts. You **do not** need to use Java code for putting the facts into working memory - you can write a rule for that; the RHS will do it. And you **do not** need to declare the types PxRow, PyRow, PzRow as Java code; a DRL declare will serve equally well. -- AFAIK, Drools has been used with my proposal in the insurance business; IIRC, their table had 50k rows.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that I may define types (PxRow, etc.) directly in DRL code. Now, if I understand your suggestion, I can (1) create generic util method to read any Excel file (or DB table), (2) next use this util method and fetch data from RHS code and (3) convert that data to proper facts and insert them from RHS code. Is this what you mean?

Comment: You'll find Java code for reading an Excel file in the Drools source code. Yes, you can use Java code (with some disadvantages) on the RHS of a rule. The code resulting from a declare will give you getters and setters, and a constructor with a parameter list for setting all fields. Generating all of that from a list of field+type names is a simple programming exercise.

Comment: And, of course, you could write a code generator producing Java code for matching a Contract object with a set of P*Row objects. That code would not be contained in the generic application, it would only be defined in the data fed to the generator which could be run at any convenient time, followed by Java compilation. Classes would be loaded dynamically; all that's needed is a generic interface with a call defining the table data files, and the "go" call passing the data for a Contract. The matching algorithm could be made very efficient by indexing...

Answer (score -1):

After reading the question more carefully, I would offer a few recommendations:

I'd prefer a relational database to Excel spreadsheets.

These are trivially simple calculations. I think the model is overkill. A rules engine seems like far too big a hammer for a problem of this size.

I would code it more simply.

Make the calculation interfaced based so you can modify it by injecting in a new class implementation.

Learn how to write Junit tests.

My first choice would be a simple decision table calculation, without a rules engine, maintaining the factors in a relational database.

A Rete rules engine is a big hammer for if/else or switch statements.  I think it's overkill unless you're leveraging induction features.

I would not put anything in session.  I'm envisioning an idempotent REST service that takes in a request and returns a response with premium and whatever else has to come back.

It sounds to me like you are grossly overcomplicating the solution prematurely.  Do the simplest thing that can possibly work; measure the performance; refactor as needed based on the data you get back and requirements.

How experienced a developer are you?  Are you alone or part of a team?  Is this a new system that's never been done by you before?

Comment: While I agree with "grossly overcomplicating" I'm not so ready to deny that a RBS could be useful here. Matching the data is kept separate from the application, and changes in the data have little or no impact on the application logic  - only the rule(s) change.

Comment: It's possible to keep such separation without resorting to a rules engine.